# Looking for Decent reports about current Patch level of server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

We are currently using WSUS on a mix of 2008 and 2008R2 servers. What I am looking for is a good way to report back to myself and Management the current state of patching on servers across several domains and sites. I know WSUS has some but they really aren't up to scratch.  How is everyone doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The wsus reports are ok but simple and don't give anything like an overview for multiple domains. Are you aware of the wsus rollup reporting tool?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/bb466192

If you can pull everything into a single server then using reporting services or even excel would allow you to put together your own reports as you wanted.

Patchaholic has some good info on doing this yourself: http://msmvps.com/blogs/athif/archive/category/2169.aspx

Other than that you are looking at an MSP type management solution like kaseya or labtech, to name just two. There are a lot of them out there but you're talking quite a bit of cash annually as they independently scan each node and not the wsus server.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Patch level is vague. What specifically are you looking for? Updates applied? Updates waiting to be applied? etc.

[Microsoft's Baseline Security Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7558) tool may be what you are looking for. It allows you to audit what updates are applied and poll windows updates to show what's missing.

If you only need what updates were applied you can easily pull this with

> Get-Hotfix -ComputerName someserver

If you wanted to do in Powershell  against a list of servers and then export the output to different text files you can use:

> $serverlist = cat "serverlist.txt" foreach ($server in $serverlist)
>
> {
>
> Get-Hotfix -ComputerName $server >> $server".txt"
>
> }

If pending updates are a concern it looks like there is another script that may be of use [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/183663/how-can-i-find-out-how-many-updates-are-waiting-to-be-installed-on-a-remote-serv)